# Past values of Y correlated with future values of X1 in fixed effects model: use instrumental variable?

Tags: stata, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables

I am using panel data, running a fixed effects regression using `xtreg Y X1 X2 X3, fe`. I suspect, however, that past values of `Y` are correlated with future values of one of the regressors e.g. `X1`. This means that the strict exogeneity assumption of fixed effects regression will be violated.

To correct for this, can I use an IV? I have another variable `Z1` which is correlated with `X1` but uncorrelated with `Y` once all other regressors are controlled for.

Could I, for example, run `ivreg Y X2 X3 ... Xn (X1=Z1)`? How would I interpret my results?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use a first difference estimator here since it only needs weak exogeneity:

$$E[\varepsilon_{it} \vert \alpha_{i},x_{i1},...,x_{it}]=0.$$

This permits *future* values of the regressors to be correlated with the error. If there is feedback from today's idiosyncratic shock to a covariate tomorrow, you should still be OK with FD.

In Stata, you can estimate FD with:

```
D.(y x1 x2 x3), vce(cluster id) noconstant
```

Omit the `noconstant` if a linear trend in levels makes sense in your undifferenced model.